# Durandal router cacheViews not working (v2.1.0)

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I am trying to figure out how to use the Durandal v2.1.0 router to navigate between views using the ***router.navigate();*** function. I have been able to navigate back and forth between two views but each time the view is recreated. I want to be able to cache these views so if the router routes to a view that has already been activated once it will simply get the existing view from the cache (along with it's current viewmodel state such as observable values, etc...).

I though that I could just use the ***cacheViews: true*** option in my router binding in the shell but this doesn't seem to be working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... it turns out that caching is working by default and I misunderstood how the caching system works. In my case, I had been executing all of the view initialization functionality inside the ***activate*** function of the viewmodel. However, this ***activate*** function is executed each time you route to a new view thus my initialization functionality was being re-run each time the view was navigated to. A simple solution was to just put an ***ifActivated*** flag inside the activate function and only run the initialization functionality if this was the first time that the view had been activated.